# How to Cache Real-time Data?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, mschart, dde

- I'm working on a windows forms application (.NET 4.0).
- My form contains a 'Fast Line' chart using the Microsoft chart control included in VS2010.
- The chart gets filled with about 20,000 datapoints.
- My application then starts receiving market data from a server via DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) in real-time and adds it the chart.

***Note:*** I have no control over the server and so I have to deal with DDE only even though it's an outdated technology. VS doesn't support DDE anymore and so I use the [Ndde](http://ndde.codeplex.com/) library which works like a charm.

First we connect to the server, create an advise loop, and then subscribe to the OnAdvise event to receive notifications of new data:

```vb
Dim client As DdeClient = New DdeClient("ServerApplication", "Bid")

Private Sub StartDDE()
    client.Connect()
    client.StartAdvise("EURUSD", 1, True, 60000)
    AddHandler client.Advise, AddressOf OnAdvise
End Sub
```

Now we can put the commands to update the chart inside the event:

```vb
Private Sub OnAdvise(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As DdeAdviseEventArgs)
    Dim myPrice As Double = args.Text
    Chart1.Series("Bid").Points.AddY(myPrice)
End Sub
```

You get the idea.

**THE PROBLEM:**

This works fine for a few seconds until the chart crashes throwing the exception:
"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

I spent a lot of time researching what may be the cause of this in my particular case, and I've come to the conclusion that it's because the chart is receiving data quicker than it can handle. It's already loaded with a lot of data and needs a certain time (less than a second) to add the received data in a new DataPoint and invalidate (refresh) itself. Whereas the server often sends data values very quickly (for example 5ms in between). So I've tried the following:

```vb
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800)
Chart1.Series("Bid").Points.AddY(myPrice)
```

thus pausing the application to give time to the chart to finish its work before adding a new point, and guess what? The application now works for minutes before throwing the exception. (altering the value in Sleep() doesn't help any further however)

The only help I could find online is an old post of someone mentioning that you should put incoming data on a cache queue, with one new data value released from the cash at a time (every time the chart finishes working).

My question is how would you do this?

Other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Are you by any chance updating the chart data collection from a non-UI thread?

Comment: This does sound like a threading issue - something is trying to modify the collection while it is being enumerated.

Comment: OnAdvise is an event delegate function right? Try Invoking the method AddY instead of executing. (Or better yet, look at InvokeRequired value. Supposedly this value is true, which I think it is, you can not safely call it from that function without Invoking it (passing the data to the other thread synchronously)). However, what needs to be done is that you keep the added points in a structure, and add them all AFTER you stop iterating the data points. The collection is then not altered while iterating and the next pass will have updated data.

Comment: @Gabe & rsbarro: Yes it appears so. @Derk-Jan Karrenbeld: Thanks for your suggestions, I'm looking into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely an issue caused by attempting to modify a UI element from a thread other than the UI thread.

The way you have it coded now the `DdeClient.Advise` event handler is being executed on a worker thread managed by the library. See, DDE sucks and because it sucks it has these requirements that it has to run on a thread with a message pump.<sup>1</sup> To make the library compatible with other types of applications besides windows forms I coded it in such a manner that it will create a dedicated thread with a message loop and marshal all of the operations onto that thread by default.

But, you can override this behavior by specifying an `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance manually in the `DdeClient` constructor. The library will then use whatever thread is hosting the `ISynchronizeInvoke` instance for all of its DDE operations. All `Form` and `Control` instances implement `ISynchronizeInvoke` so it is easy enough to tell the library to use the main UI thread.

```
Dim client As DdeClient = New DdeClient("ServerApplication", "Bid", yourForm)
```

If you tell the library to use your `Form` instance then the `Advise` event handlers will be executed on the same thread hosting that `Form`; the UI thread.

By the way, I realize that you have no control over the server, but I would at least begin talking with the vendor of the software to use more modern (not 20 years old) mechanisms for doing interprocess communications.

---

<sup>1</sup>It also has the unfortunate requirement of thread affinity which made dealing with the garbage collector a real pain.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the insight Brian. Oh and I couldn't agree more about DDE. I am emailing the vendor as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Get real ;) DDE is slow, graphics is slow. Do not do them in the same thread.

Try that:

- Create a second thread that handles DDE, queues the items.
- The  chart thread then pulls the updates and draws them.

Now, here comes the point:

- ONLY the ui thread is allowed to modify the chart control. Yes, sucks. No, not negotiable. - old UI rule since the dawn of time.
- Threads needs locking ;)